# change a GET method URL to SEO URL in Joomla 3 component

Tags: url-rewriting, seo, joomla3.0, joomla-component

I want to send a parameter form a module to a component in Joomla 3 (it's a date to show its articles).

So I send the date by GET Method like this:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/web43/archives.html?date=2014-12-29&option=com_arch&Itemid=10371">
  list of articles on 2014/12/29
</a>
```

Everything works. I can get parameters on PHP file in model folder in com_arch component...
but this URL is ugly and unfriendly for search engines.

I want something like this:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/web43/archives/2014-12-29">
  list of articles on 2/2/2014
</a>
```

Is it possible? How can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps: 
http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Its about router.php file.